# MSF4J POST method receiving partial data

Tags: rest, post, wso2, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I'm new to MSF4J and I need to write a REST API that accepts a large XML data through POST. I am using
`request.getMessegeBody()`
method to get the data. I discovered that it's now deprecated but I couldn't find the newer version of it so I decided to use it anyway.

The problem is, when I send data to the microservice for the first time, it doesn't get the whole data. All the subsequent requests will get the full message body except the first.

When I try passing the request through ESB, ESB receives the whole body but when it reaches the endpoint it will be truncated.

I have also tried sending requests from different rest clients but for the first time it always gets the incomplete message body

```
@POST
@Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json", "text/xml" })
@Path("test/")
public Response getReqNotification(@Context Request request) throws Exception {
    Response.ResponseBuilder respBuilder =         
    Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(request);
    ByteBuf b = request.getMessageBody();
    byte[] bb = new byte[b.readableBytes()];
    b.duplicate().readBytes(bb);
    System.out.println(new String(bb));

    return respBuilder.build();
}
```

I expect it to print the full message(which is about 2000 bytes long) every time when I send a request, but I'm only getting around 800 bytes when I first run the microservice.

I hope ill get assistance here. I have tried elsewhere but wso2 doesn't have much documentation (⌣_⌣”)

Comment: Can you try to read the message as in https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/wso2/msf4j/service/TestMicroservice.java#L225

Comment: Thank you very much! This link is so helpful, I'll actually bookmark it. I will now post the code that worked shortly......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't really understand what I was doing wrong but with the help of [this link](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/wso2/msf4j/service/TestMicroservice.java#L225) I have managed to come up with the following code and it works fine.

The major cha is that I now use `request.getMessageContentStream()` instead of the depricated `request.getMessageBody()`

```
@Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json", "text/xml" })
@Path("test/")
public Response getReqNotification(@Context Request request) throws Exception {
        Response.ResponseBuilder respBuilder =         
        Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(request);
        String data = "";

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(request.getMessageContentStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            int d;
            while ((d = bis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(d);
            }
            data = bos.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data);
//////do stuff

        return respBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: AS I remember getMessageBody only returns the first chunk. Whereas if you have multiple chunks you are not reading the full message.

Comment: Oh, now I see! thanks for the clarification. I really appreciate